# ASP.NET: TableCell size problem

Tags: asp.net, tablecell

I would like to ask why setting the size of a TableCell when dynamically rendering the ASP.NET table does not take in effect?

for example:

```
Table table = new Table();
TableRow row = new TableRow();

TableCell cell = new TableCell;
cell.Width = 30;
cell.Height = 30;

row.Cells.Add(cell);

//.... 10 more cells

table.Rows.Add(row);
```

why are the size of the cells unchanged?

Comment: Is that property read only? i haven't checked

Comment: What does the actual rendered HTML look like? On a semi-related note, you may want to consider setting such attributes via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to size them with a [`Unit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit(loband).aspx) struct. Just providing a numerical value does not indicate what type of unit (pixels, percentage, em, ex, inch, *etc*) to use.

```
Unit width = new Unit(30, UnitType.Pixel);
TableCell cell = new TableCell();

cell.Width = width;
```

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if you can assign the width as `cell.Width = 30;`

try `cell.Width = Unit.Pixel(30);`

also if you are adding `multiple rows` then your width may increase be because of the width given to a corresponding `cell` in some other row.

Comment: Hey, i have learnt wcf as per your guidance, please tell me something more that will help me in future with interviews. can i give my mailid? thank you. please reply.